# Inconsistency on deleted posts notices

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, post-notice

Despite the fact that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18770168/5468463) has been deleted by a mod, its following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770631/5468463) is marked as *'deleted by the author'*:

> [image]

The author profile shows that the author has not been active since 11/2018 and the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18770631/timeline) confirms that there were no intervention from the author.
I think it is also curious to see "undelete" vote coming up to life from the past, as, again, the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18770631/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) shows the last undelete vote was back in 2013.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: The author *did* delete their post, back in 2013.  Then undeleted it again, but the system doesn't keep a record of every deletion.  So you only see the first.

Comment: I know that from the timeline. But it should be canceled with the undeletion that happened since

Comment: @HansPassant the table do keeps record of deletion/undeletion events, otherwise the timeline would not be as useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Some details:

- The deleted post notice gets information on who deleted the post from the last `PostHistory` entry for the post relating to deletion.
- This works fine for regular deletions. However, when an answer is deleted merely because its parent question was deleted, there is no `PostHistory` event left on the answer.
- In cases where the answer had not been previously deleted and undeleted, this didn't really matter - the deletion notice was just shown with less detail (since there was no `PostHistory` entry).
- However, in cases like this, the deleted post notice would show details from the original deletion (since it was the last `PostHistory` entry on the answer).

To fix this, answers deleted along with their questions will now show a notice that looks like this:

[image: Deletion post notice with text: "This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted last year along with its parent question."]

The text says:

> **This answer is hidden**. This answer was deleted last year along with its parent question.

This should avoid issues as described in this post, and also is generally more accurate than we had been doing previously.

---

> Delete a question
> Answers deleted as well
> Improved notice text