# I got a "removed" (not "user removed") message in my reputation tab, what does it mean?

Tags: support, bug, deleted-answers

I got a *removed* message in my reputation tab.

Does that mean a user removed their question, and so my answer have been removed with it?

Or does it mean that the community removed the question?

Or is it only my answer that was removed?

I'm really comfused, and whenever I try to search things like "what does removed mean?", 
I only see posts that explain what *user* removed means.

[image]

#### There also seem to be a bug:

[image]

***I* did not delete the answer.**

Comment: are you able to find your answer related to that question? if so you can easily see if it was removed or not

Comment: One of [the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614674/replacing-characters-a-to-w-and-w-to-a-in-a-string) you answered has been deleted and with it your answer. That's why you lost the reputation from that answer.

Comment: Why was it deleted? The OP showed what they had tried, and the answer had many votes :/

Comment: Closed as a duplicate 5 days ago, deleted 36 minutes ago for that reason (presumably)

Comment: @Zoe But I don't see what's so special about that question that makes it necessary to deleted. Countless other closed questions don't get deleted.

Comment: yes, because there's not nearly enough delete votes to get everything. There's also some with so-called "historical value" that get locked in spite of being off-topic. That question was yet another duplicate that didn't add much to what was already posted. Deletion made sense

Comment: Any closed question may be deleted at any time. Some automatically, others manually. A duplicate is only safe from deletion if it provides a novel way to ask the question (thus helping with searchability).

Comment: The message is probably a bug. I guess the system got confused because you deleted and undeleted this post before. Feel free to report this bug in a separate question and tag it as [tag:bug-reports]

Comment: The message on the deleted post might be related as a bug: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398107/5468463

Comment: You are correct that if a question has upvotes it is less likely to be deleted. A question with an accepted or positively scored answer will not be automatically deleted by the system. However, in this case, 3 users with more than 10,000 reputation voted for deletion because they felt it added no lasting value to the site. Since your answer was not visible on the site for at least 60 days, you lost the reputation gained.

Comment: Although I cannot speak for the three users who cast their votes to delete, when I use my deletion votes, I try to consider the post as a whole, taking into account how other members of the community have viewed the value of the questions and answers as expressed by the number of votes. Additionally, very popular questions require more deletion votes to delete. However, it merely requires 1 additional vote for every [20 net positive score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071). In this case, that rule did not apply.

Comment: does every [20 net negative score](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=20+net+negative+score) require 1 more undelete vote to undelete?

Comment: I believe every undelete requires only 3 votes, but I cannot seem to find a reference at the moment.

Comment: maybe it's time to consider closing more than answering. You are around for while and you should have noticed that there is a lot of duplicate and repeated question. I see you have only casted 9 duplicates votes (https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/854207/how-to-get-the-number-of-closure-votes-by-type?UserId=13552470) I am pretty sure you faced more in the python tag. You have also answered 55 duplicate actually

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When I search ***what does "removed" mean***, this is the only question I can find that explains that it means a *post* (not a user) have been removed.

#### To those who might have the same question, the answer is:

**A question with your answer on it have been removed. Don't try to search for the question if your reputation is lower than 10K, as you won't be able to find it.**

Answer (score 10):

This is a bug, which has been present for a long time now. Whenever you delete one of your posts it uses one of your delete votes. You have 5 special delete votes, which you can use on your own posts regardless of reputation.

The bug happens when you undelete a post. The delete vote is not invalidated and it is treated as a normal 20k delete vote. If your post would be negatively scoring then it would only require 2 more 20k users to delete it.

In this case, the question was deleted by 3 users who decided this duplicate added no value, but the system saw your pending delete vote and determined that you deleted the answer, but in reality the question was deleted by 3 users and your answer was automatically deleted by the system together with the question.

Comment: @AnnZen Yes, you can ask the community to reconsider if you have valid points that there was value lost by deleting it. However, the question was closed as a duplicate so you would need to convince us that this was not a duplicate or that this duplicate will be a good sign-post in the future.