# Post deletion banner lists incorrect users

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, deleted-answers, post-notice

When a post was deleted via review and then later undeleted and deleted again, the deletion banner lists the users who took part in the original review rather than whoever deleted it afterwards. While this might make sense for when moderators handle the dispute flags, it doesn't make sense if 3 users decide to delete an answer regardless of the review outcome.

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47089782/1839439) lists 4 users as the ones who deleted it, but the timeline shows 3 different users.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related MSE posts about this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336092 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290623. Also, related MSO post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398107

Comment: I'll [status-review] this one since none of the MSE ones are marked as such. That should at least get a dev to look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed earlier this week. We are now showing the users involved in the most recent deletion history (whether it's from review or not), and this fix applies retroactively to all the previously deleted posts.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that this does not apply to mod-deletions after handling the dispute flag? What about the similar reports https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409140/post-deletion-banner-lists-incorrect-users#comment854588_409140

Comment: @Dharman Not sure I follow. If a mod deleted an answer, the mod should show up in the post notice. As for the similar reports, the MSE ones are the same thing, but the MSO link is slightly different. I'm looking into it a little bit right now, but it's a more complicated case and will likely have to be fixed another time.